# Does pelón/pelona mean bald or hairy?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, definiciones, adjetivos

I have heard *pelón* (or the feminine *pelona*) used to both refer to someone who has no hair and someone who has a lot of hair. Is there any way of distinguishing whether *pelón* means bald or hairy, or is context the only indicator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the RAE, *[pelón](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=pel%F3n)* means someone who has little or no hair, and that it means "with a lot of hair" in Ecuador.

[A topic](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1205805) on Wordreference.com confirms this, so does looking the word up on [Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=pel%C3%B3n).

So I think you can go on using pelón safely to say "bald or with little hair".

Answer (score 1):

We use *peluda* which means 'hairy' in Spanish. *Pelon* is used for someone that is bald. I've never heard *pelona* used as hairy but I'm sure some latinos use it as an informal way of saying 'hairy' in Spanish. It's definitely understood used in context. I mean, I would understand it once I grasped what was being said. Trust me, as latinos here in the US the Spanish language is constantly being changed/updated with very informal forms of the use of the language and Spanglish is also a new form of speaking. I personally hate it as it's destroying the romantic form of it but once explained it's pretty much understood and a given that's what the local form of speaking or understanding the Spanish language in certain areas will be.

Comment: Not to be confused with pelado, which also means bald.